# Chamando método do Controller e recebo o print da função

Tags: javascript, react, controller, hapijs

Quando eu chamo o Método do Controller para listar os usuarios, ao inves de me retornar a array ele me retorna o print da função

Código do controller:

```
export default userController = {
    Listar: () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user').then(function(resposta){
        return resposta.data;
      })
    }
}
```

Dando o console.log para ver o retorno:

```
    componentDidMount(){
      console.log(userController.Listar());
    }
```

Alguém por favor sabe me dizer o motivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro Verifique se seu controller está importado neste documento por exemplo:

```
import userController from "./userController";
```

Depois coloque o console log dentro da função para ver se tem retorno.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        getUserData();
    }

    export function* getUserData() {
      try {
         LoadingActions.uiStartLoading();

        //chamada a API para capturar o user
        const data = yield call(api.get, "/api/logged_user");

        console.log("resposta", data); <---- SEU CONSOLE LOG

        yield UsersActions.getUserRequest(data);

        //Disparando a action de loading
        LoadingActions.uiStopLoading();
      } catch (error) {
         console.log("TCL: getUserData -> error", error);

         yield put(
         UsersActions.getUserFailure("Não foi possível buscar dados do usuário!")
    );
  }
```

Abraços

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema dando um return antes do axios.get  `return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user').then(function(resposta){
        return resposta.data;
      })`

Comment: AHh sim make sense, eu mandei este exemplo que é como se fosse um async/await porém uma função generator que também faz um retorno. Aconselho fazer um try/catch pra caso essa requisição falhe. Abraços!